# Python-Binance module futures_historical_klines start_str is not working

Tags: python

I'm trying to get Klines for 15 ago to now and I tried this code

```
 self.client = Connect().make_connection()
 print("logged in")
    time= datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
    time_ago=datetime.datetime.now()- datetime.timedelta(minutes=15)
    time_ago = time_ago.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
    time = str(time)
    time_ago = str(time_ago)
    print(time,time_ago)
    print(self.client.futures_historical_klines(
        symbol='ETHUSDT',
        interval='1m',
        start_str=time,
        end_str=time_ago))
```

but this returns `[]` how can I work this code where is my mistake

EDIT:
I have solve the problem with changing my computers timezone to etc

Comment: The start should be `time_ago` and end `time` or just don't set an end

Comment: I've tried replacing time to time_ago and time_ago to time and still remains same and I deleted the end but still same